# Postgresql recursive query invalid reference to FROM-clause

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I'm trying to do a recursive query to get all directories and documents inside a directory.
i would be so thankful if someone could point me in the right direction.

i tried this but it returns an error

```
        WITH RECURSIVE FilesInDir AS (
            SELECT
                dir.id as dirid,
                dir.directoryid,
                doc.id as docid
            FROM
                directory dir,
                document doc
            WHERE
                dir.id = 17
            UNION
                SELECT
                    dir.id as dirid,
                    dir.directoryId,
                    doc.id as docid
                FROM
                    directory dir,
                    document doc
                INNER JOIN FilesInDir fid ON fid.dirid = dir.directoryid
        ) SELECT
            *
        From
            FilesInDir;
```

errors:

```
[102] ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "dir" at character 353
[102] HINT:  There is an entry for table "dir", but it cannot be referenced from this
 part of the query.
```

I got it working with all directories in the directory... but i need directories and documents

```
        WITH RECURSIVE FilesInDir AS (
            SELECT
                id,
                directoryid
            FROM
                directory
            WHERE
                id = 17
            UNION
                SELECT
                    dir.id,
                    dir.directoryId
                FROM
                    directory dir
                INNER JOIN FilesInDir fid ON fid.id = dir.directoryid
        ) SELECT
            *
        From
            FilesInDir;
```

this is my database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Repository(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  repositoryName VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Directory(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  directoryName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  directoryId INTEGER REFERENCES Directory(id),
  repositoryId INTEGER REFERENCES Repository(id) NOT NULL,
  markdeleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
  UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (directoryname, directoryid, repositoryId));

CREATE TABLE Document(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  documentName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  directoryId INTEGER REFERENCES Directory(id),
  repositoryId INTEGER REFERENCES Repository(id) NOT NULL,
  markdeleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
  UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (documentname, directoryid, repositoryid));
```

Comment: You aren't linking the `directory` and `document` tables anywhere in here.  Are you missing `INNER JOIN` clauses in both queries?  Wouldn't it be better if you had one `DirectoryEntry` table that included a "type"?

Comment: @TimRoberts The field `directoryId` in the `directory` and `document` table are the links or do you mean something else? also the inner join clauses are there in both queries. you're probably right that a `DirectoryEntry` table would be better... didn't think about it.

Comment: Yes, but you do not have `WHERE dir.directoryId = doc.directoryId` anywhere here, so they aren't linked.  Your query will return EVERY row of `doc` joined with the rows of `dir` where the id=17.

Comment: @TimRoberts i'm not sure if i understand you correctly... buut if i have something like `WHERE dir.directoryId = doc.directoryId` doesn't that mean i won't get anything returned if there aren't any documents?oh so you are saying i'm missing the doc.directoryId from the query?

Comment: Yes, but the alternative is to return EVERY document for every query.  Your design is flawed.  You could try doing a UNION of "all directories within this directory" and "all documents within this directory", but I'm still not convinced that will work.

Comment: @TimRoberts Would it be easier if i would have a table `DirectoryEntry` like you suggested?

Comment: @mewsen Take the result of your working query to build the directory tree and then `left join` it to your `document` table.  There is too much wrong with your first query to cover all the details.  The most egregious error is what @TimRoberts is pointing out to you.  Do not use the ancient implicit `cross join` syntax by separating tables with commas.  Use explicit `joins` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  It's sensible enough to fetch "all directories in a directory" and "all documents within a directory", but I don't see what you gain by trying  recursive query.  Surely any program using this structure needs to handle the subdirectories in a special way anyway.